# Sorting each row of numpy multidimensional array in decreasing order

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np.array:

```
arr = [[ 0.4472136  -0.54707327  0.57708891  0.20546525 -0.35420794]
      [ 0.4472136  -0.23091006 -0.40818058  0.5190655   0.55735103]
      [ 0.4472136  -0.2850627  -0.35696504 -0.76864019 -0.02252698]
      [ 0.4472136   0.55494541  0.51548435 -0.19768884  0.43270151]
      [ 0.4472136   0.50810061 -0.32742763  0.24179828 -0.61331762]]
```

If I do `arr2 = np.sort(arr[:, ::-1])`, I get:

```
arr2 = [[-0.54707327 -0.35420794  0.20546525  0.4472136   0.57708891]
       [-0.40818058 -0.23091006  0.4472136   0.5190655   0.55735103]
       [-0.76864019 -0.35696504 -0.2850627  -0.02252698  0.4472136 ]
       [-0.19768884  0.43270151  0.4472136   0.51548435  0.55494541]
       [-0.61331762 -0.32742763  0.24179828  0.4472136   0.50810061]]
```

So the first row of expected output would be:

```
arr2 = [[0.57708891  0.4472136  0.20546525  -0.35420794  -0.54707327]
       ...]
```

But this gives me in increasing order and I want each row in decreasing order. I've tried multiple ways with arr.sort and np.sort(arr) along with doing multiple reverses but couldn't get it to work. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse the array after sorting it, like so:

```py
arr2 = np.sort(arr)[:, ::-1]
```

Also using `np.sort(arr[:, ::-1])` does not seem much different from `np.sort(arr)`. In the first case you are simply reversing the array before sorting it anyways.